# How do I add a System.Collections.ArrayList to a PowerShell custom object?

Tags: powershell, arraylist, pscustomobject

My goal is to create a custom data object that has two discrete variables (`fooName` and `fooUrl`) and a list of `fooChildren`, each list item having two discrete variables variables `childAge` and `childName`.

Currently, I have this:

```
$fooCollection = [PSCustomObject] @{fooName=""; fooUrl=""; fooChildrenList=@()} 

$fooCollection.fooName = "foo-a-rama"
$fooCollection.fooUrl = "https://1.2.3.4"

$fooChild = New-Object -TypeName PSobject
$fooChild | Add-Member -Name childAge -MemberType NoteProperty -Value 6
$fooChild | Add-Member -Name childName -MemberType NoteProperty -Value "Betsy"
$fooCollection.fooChildrenList += $fooChild

$fooChild = New-Object -TypeName PSobject
$fooChild | Add-Member -Name childAge -MemberType NoteProperty -Value 10
$fooChild | Add-Member -Name childName -MemberType NoteProperty -Value "Rolf"
$fooCollection.fooChildrenList += $fooChild

cls
$fooCollection.fooName
$fooCollection.fooUrl

foreach ($fooChild in $fooCollection.fooChildrenList)
{
    ("  " + $fooChild.childName + " " + $fooChild.childAge)
}
```

Which produces the following. So far so good

```
foo-a-rama
https://1.2.3.4
  Betsy 6
  Rolf 10
```

**Problem**: I don't like using `+=` because as I understand it, using `+=` results in a copy of `$fooCollection.fooChildrenList` being created (in whatever state it's in) each time `+=` is executed.

So, instead of implementing `fooChildrenList` as `@()`, I want to implement `fooChildrenList` as `New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList` so I can add each row as needed. I've tried various ways of doing this in code but `fooChildrenList` winds up being unpopulated. For example:

```
$fooCollection = [PSCustomObject] @{fooName=""; fooUrl=""; fooChildrenList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList} 

$fooCollection.fooName = "foo-a-rama"
$fooCollection.fooUrl = "https://1.2.3.4"

$fooChild.childName = "Betsy"
$fooChild.childAge = 6
$fooCollection.fooChildrenList.Add((New-Object PSObject -Property $fooChild))

$fooChild.childName = "Rolf"
$fooChild.childAge = 10
$fooCollection.fooChildrenList.Add((New-Object PSObject -Property $fooChild))
```

`$fooCollection | get-member` shows

```
TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name            MemberType   Definition                                   
----            ----------   ----------                                   
Equals          Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)               
GetHashCode     Method       int GetHashCode()                            
GetType         Method       type GetType()                               
ToString        Method       string ToString()                            
fooChildrenList NoteProperty System.Collections.ArrayList fooChildrenList=
fooName         NoteProperty string fooName=foo-a-rama                    
fooUrl          NoteProperty string fooUrl=https://1.2.3.4
```

`$fooCollection` shows

```
fooName         : foo-a-rama
fooUrl          : https://1.2.3.4
fooChildrenList : {}
```

How do I add a System.Collections.ArrayList to a PowerShell custom object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well im not sure what issue you are getting it works fine for me

```
function New-Child([string]$Name, [int]$Age){
    $Child = New-Object -TypeName PSobject
    $Child | Add-Member -Name childAge -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $age -PassThru | 
    Add-Member -Name childName -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $name
    return $child
}

$fooCollection = [PSCustomObject] @{fooName=""; fooUrl=""; fooChildrenList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList} 

$fooCollection.fooName = "foo-a-rama"
$fooCollection.fooUrl = "https://1.2.3.4"
$fooCollection.fooChildrenList.Add((New-Child -Name "Betty" -Age 9)) | Out-Null
$fooCollection.fooChildrenList.Add((New-Child -Name "Ralf" -Age 15)) | Out-Null

$fooCollection.fooName
$fooCollection.fooUrl
foreach ($fooChild in $fooCollection.fooChildrenList)
{
    "  " + $fooChild.childName + " " + $fooChild.childAge
}
```

output

```
foo-a-rama
https://1.2.3.4
  Betty 9
  Ralf 15
```

Comment: I was in the same ballpark as you, but I have to assume the way I was trying to create the new 'child' object was the problem (see my code under the heading **Problem** in my original post above). In any case, your solution works. My answer below seems to mimic yours kind of obliquely :-)

Comment: @NovaSysEng: The _immediate_ problem with your code - as posted - is that you can't pass an existing `[pscustomobject]` / `[psobject]` instance to `New-Object PSObject -Property` so as to _create a copy of it_; the potential _conceptual_ problem is that if you do _not_ create a copy, you'll end up with a list whose elements all point to the very same object. ArcSet's answer avoids this problem by ensuring that a _new_ custom-object instance is returned whenever function `New-Child` is called. Given your own answer, it sounds like adding the same object every time was indeed your true problem.

Comment: I would love to say my answer is right...and though my answer is correct. @Mklement0 answer is far more understandable and delivers a far more useful information then mine :) but thank your for accepting mine. But you might want to accept Mklement0's

Answer (score 3):

The **challenge is to add a *copy* of the `$fooChild` `[pscustomobject]` instance you're *re-using* every time you add to the list** with `.Add()` (if you don't use a copy, you'll end up with all list elements pointing to the *same* object).

However, **you cannot clone an existing `[pscustomobject]` (a.k.a `[psobject]`) instance with `New-Object PSObject -Property`**.

One option (PSv3+) is to **define the reusable `$fooChild` as an *ordered hashtable* instead, and then use a `[pscustomobject]` *cast***, which implicitly creates a new object every time:

```
$fooCollection = [PSCustomObject] @{ fooChildrenList = New-Object Collections.ArrayList } 

# Create the reusable $fooChild as an *ordered hashtable* (PSv3+)
$fooChild = [ordered] @{ childName = ''; childAge = -1 }

# Create 1st child and add to list with [pscustomobject] cast
$fooChild.childName = 'Betsy'; $fooChild.childAge = 6
$null = $fooCollection.fooChildrenList.Add([pscustomobject] $fooChild)

# Create and add another child.
$fooChild.childName = 'Rolf'; $fooChild.childAge = 10
$null = $fooCollection.fooChildrenList.Add([pscustomobject] $fooChild)

# Output the children
$fooCollection.fooChildrenList
```

<sup>Note the `$null = ...`, which suppresses the typically unwanted output from the `.Add()` method call.</sup>

The above yields:

```
childName childAge
--------- --------
Betsy            6
Rolf            10
```

---

A **slightly more obscure alternative** is to stick with `$fooChild` as a `[pscustomobject]` instance and call **`.psobject.Copy()`** on it to create a clone.

---

[ArcSet's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52336763/45375) provides a more modular solution that **creates new custom-object instances on demand via a *helper function***.

---

Finally, in **PSv5+** you could **define a helper *class***:

```
$fooCollection = [PSCustomObject] @{ fooChildrenList = New-Object Collections.ArrayList } 

# Define helper class
class FooChild {
  [string] $childName
  [int]    $childAge
}

# Create 1st child and add to list with [pscustomobject] cast
$null = $fooCollection.fooChildrenList.Add([FooChild] @{ childName = 'Betsy'; childAge = 6 })

# Create and add another child.
$null = $fooCollection.fooChildrenList.Add([FooChild] @{ childName = 'Rolf'; childAge = 10 })

# Output the children
$fooCollection.fooChildrenList
```

Note how instances of `[FooChild]` can be created by simply casting a hashtable that has entries matching the class property names.

Answer (score 0):

Quick copy paste from something I have that I use to make some of my Arrays. I have to create the custom objects and then add them to the Array. It will need modified for your scenario but I think it will get you what you need.

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$SQL_Query_Results = @()

ForEach ($SQL_Index in $SQL_Table) {

    $SQL_Array_Object = [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Computer_Name'    = $SQL_Table[$SQL_Index_Counter].ComputerID -replace ",", ""
        'Project'          = $SQL_Table[$SQL_Index_Counter].Project
        'Site'             = $SQL_Table[$SQL_Index_Counter].Site
        'Description'      = $SQL_Table[$SQL_Index_Counter].Description -replace ",", ""
        'Physical_Machine' = $SQL_Table[$SQL_Index_Counter].IsPhysicalMachine
        'Active'           = $SQL_Table[$SQL_Index_Counter].IsActive
    }

    $SQL_Query_Results.Add($SQL_Array_Object) | Out-Null
}
```

Edited to show how Array was initially created.

Comment: I assume `$SQL_Query_Results` was defined as `$SQL_Query_Results = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList` ?

Comment: `[System.Collections.ArrayList]$SQL_Query_Results = @()` is how I did the initial creation

Comment: what's the type for `$SQL_Table` and where does `$SQL_Index_Counter` come from (as in `$SQL_Table[$SQL_Index_Counter].ComputerID -replace ",", ""`)? (I don't see `$SQL_Index_Counter` initialized or incremented)

Comment: For that specific scenario, it was all `String` but i have used `Int`, `bool`, `datetime`, etc as well. It will be what you have it defined as when you store it in the `PSCustomObject`

Comment: Sorry, also, I just realized - I'm trying to implement a `System.Collections.ArrayList` inside a `PSCustomObject` (or otherwise avoid using `+=`). This example doesn't crack that nut